# Replace the numbers of a dataframe by their current streak

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

My goal is to replace all the numbers of the dataframe by their current positive streak number. It works well but the coding is messy because I do it one column by one column. And I always mention the column name manually. So I guess there is a better way to do it with just a small part of coding.

Would you have an idea how to simplify my code by any chance ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[9, 5, 2], [-2, 6, -4], [-5, 1, -1], [9, 6, -5], [7, -1, -3], [6, -4, 1], 
              [2, -9, 3]],
             columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

def streaks(df, col):
    sign = np.sign(df[col])
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    return df.assign(A=s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs())
df = streaks(df, 'A')

def streaks(df, col):
    sign = np.sign(df[col])
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    return df.assign(B=s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs())
df = streaks(df, 'B')

def streaks(df, col):
    sign = np.sign(df[col])
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    return df.assign(C=s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs())
df = streaks(df, 'C')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single function:

With apply:

```
def streaks(col):
    sign = np.sign(col)
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    return  s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs()
df = df.apply(streaks)
```

Or modifying your original approach:

```
def streaks(df, col):
    sign = np.sign(df[col])
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    return df.assign(**{col: s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs()})

df = streaks(df, 'A')
df = streaks(df, 'B')
df = streaks(df, 'C')
```

Or modifying in place:

```
def streaks(df, col):
    sign = np.sign(df[col])
    s = sign.groupby((sign!=sign.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
    df[col] = s.where(s>0, 0.0).abs()

streaks(df, 'A')
streaks(df, 'B')
streaks(df, 'C')
print(df)
```